# Amazon API for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework, frameworks

Just taking a first look at PHP frameworks? I see Zend has a great Amazon API service available http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.html#zendservice-amazon-itemlookup-example-asin. However, finding Zend tricky to work with and install modules/build.

Does Laravel have a similar built in Amazon API services package available?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific Amazon API service?  Take a look to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

Comment: The ability to access Amazon product data with its API like in the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this package (AWS Service Provider for Laravel 5)](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel), made for Laravel and directly related to AWS services. It's more like a wrapper or something similar.

It is totally compatible with ~5.1, but you should be able to use without issues also on the 5.2.

Let me know if it helps :)

EDIT: Sorry, didn't understand well the question. With a search I just found [this interesting package (apai-io)](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io). The documentation, that you can [see here](http://exeu.github.io/apai-io/), has many examples, from basic usage to advanced topics. It is totally framework-agnostic, so you should not stumble upon errors related to specific frameworks and/or implementations.

It seems to do what you should need.

Comment: Got this installed now, just falling at the lasst hurdle. Actually how to pull data from Amazon product catalog within a page/

Comment: Sorry man, didn't understood the question well. When I ready about "Amazon" I automatically associate it to AWS. Take a look to my edit @merch89

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

1. Search on Packagist for suitable composer packages
2. Use the Zend's Amazon package it self on Laravel - https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon

Answer (score 0):

[Zend's Amazon package](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon) is good.

Install the package and create an object like this .

```
$amazon = new ZendService\Amazon\Amazon('AMAZON_API_KEY', 'US', 'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY');
```

Comment: I have Laravel fully installed on Cloud9, tried the above command twice with no joy. What am i doing wrong? http://i.imgur.com/wN6F10v.jpg

Comment: You have the api key and secret key ?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, its not getting that far yet anyway. Struggling to install the Zend service

Comment: So you have issue with installing the package ?

Comment: Have you added the package in composer.json and then `composer update`.

Comment: What parts do I need to add to app.js and composer.json . Following this installation guide : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/installing-package-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

If you already have api key and secret key, You can use directly the api amazon scratchpad tool.

This tool allows you to create and test your applications to the Amazon catalog.
This useful tool also provides the PHP code or java.

http://webservices.amazon.it/scratchpad/index.html

example

```
    <?php

// Your AWS Access Key ID, as taken from the AWS Your Account page
$aws_access_key_id = "YOUR ACCESS KEY";

// Your AWS Secret Key corresponding to the above ID, as taken from the AWS Your Account page
$aws_secret_key = "YOU SECRET KEY";

// The region you are interested in
$endpoint = "webservices.amazon.it"; // or other..

$uri = "/onca/xml";

$params = array(
    "Service" => "AWSECommerceService",
    "Operation" => "ItemSearch",
    "AWSAccessKeyId" => "YOUR ACCESS KEY",
    "AssociateTag" => "YOUR PERSONAL TAG",
    "SearchIndex" => "Electronics",  // or other ...
    "Keywords" => "phone",  // or other..
    "ResponseGroup" => "Images,ItemAttributes,Offers",
    "Sort" => "price"
);

// Set current timestamp if not set
if (!isset($params["Timestamp"])) {
    $params["Timestamp"] = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
}

// Sort the parameters by key
ksort($params);

$pairs = array();

foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    array_push($pairs, rawurlencode($key)."=".rawurlencode($value));
}

// Generate the canonical query
$canonical_query_string = join("&", $pairs);

// Generate the string to be signed
$string_to_sign = "GET\n".$endpoint."\n".$uri."\n".$canonical_query_string;

// Generate the signature required by the Product Advertising API
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $aws_secret_key, true));

// Generate the signed URL
$request_url = 'http://'.$endpoint.$uri.'?'.$canonical_query_string.'&Signature='.rawurlencode($signature);

echo "Signed URL: \"".$request_url."\"";

?>
```